# How to simulate an ARMA process with a regressor

Tags: r, time-series, simulation, arma, mathematical-statistics

I'd like someone to explain me the model differences between this two type of simulation:

Variables creation:

```
N=1e3

#error term and regressor
eps=rnorm(N,0,9)
x=rnorm(N)

#starting value
y0=0

y=c(y0,rep(NA,N-1))
```

Simulation Type I:

```
for(i in 2:N)
{
  y[i] = 0.75*y[i-1]+7*x[i]+eps[i]
}
```

Simulation Type II

```
for(i in 2:N)
{
  y[i] = 0.75*y[i-1]+eps[i]
}

y=y+7*x
```

As you can see, the difference is where I add the regressor.

What model am I simulating in the two cases?